# ServletContextListener error

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

Hi ihave the below code for servletcontextlistener.

```
   import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

public class ContextListener extends HttpServlet implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ServletContext context=sce.getServletContext();
        String dburl=context.getInitParameter("dbUrl");
        String dbusername=context.getInitParameter("dbUserName");
        String dbpassword=context.getInitParameter("dbPassword");

        DBConnector.createConnection(dburl, dbusername, dbpassword);
        System.out.println("Connection Establised.........");
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        DBConnector.closeConnection();
    }

}
```

and a DBConnector class as follows.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnector {

    private static Connection con;

    public static void createConnection(String dbUrl,String dbusername,String dbPassword){
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbusername, dbPassword);     
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }

    public static Connection getConnection(){
        return con;
    }

    public static void closeConnection(){
        if(con!=null){
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                 ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and in web.xml i declared as below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
    <param-name>dbUrl</param-name>
    <param-value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>dbUserName</param-name>
    <param-value>dbUserName</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>dbPassword</param-name>
    <param-value>dbPassword</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>Topical.ContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Login</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

here when i'm trying to run ContextListener.java i'm thrown an error saying "Class 'Context listener' neither has a main method nor is servlet specified in web.xml".

How do i get rid of this problem.

Thanks

Comment: How you can run a servlet without declaring in web.xml as a servlet? Split your servlet and context listener and declare both in web.xml.

Comment: Hi Ravindra can you please edit my code, i'm a newbie to this servlet concepts, i usually make all my webpages in jsps , but came to know that mvc would be a better idea, then shifted to this. Thanks

Comment: You can google for the examples. Plenty of examples are available on the web. - Here is one http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/ and for servlet http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tutorialspoint.com%2Fservlets%2Fservlets-first-example.htm&ei=Lzo3UbmZA4LMrQfI44HwDw&usg=AFQjCNF5K6jTs8e74GUiKKIU1gurYM-iGg&bvm=bv.43287494,d.bmk